# How to force hardware acceleration on iOS using Phonegap?

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, html, cordova

From what I heard Hardware Acceleration makes phonegap apps feel more "native" and run smoother. Is this true? And if so how do I enable it on iOS?

Thanks!
Samar

Comment: http://phonegap-tips.com/articles/force-hardware-acceleration-with-translate3d-sometimes.html

Comment: Best guess is that this refers to the faster JavaScript engine in Safari as opposed to WebKit. But that is hard to tell from the question.